# Angular / RxJS - chain two http get calls

Tags: angular, asynchronous, rxjs, http-get

I have a problem when retrieving the results of two http async calls.

The first route is called `/contracts` and the second route is called `/shipments` 
Each contract is related to a shipment so it has a `shipmentId` property.
I want to retrieve all the contracts and for each contract get his respective shipment from my REST server.

I tried calling both the `getContracts()` and `getShipments()` and then forEach contract to use find in my `shipments[]` (the result from `getShipments()` method) but sometimes the shipments call response returns after the contracts call response and so a `cannot read property x of undefined` error is returned.

I tried using also `getShipmentById()` but this doesn't assures me that all the time the shipment will be returned after the contract.

How can this be achieved using Angular / RxJS?

Here are relevant parts of my code:

```
  getContracts(): Observable<Contract[]> {
    return this.http.get<Contract[]>(this.contractsUrl)
      .pipe(
        retry(3),
        catchError(this.handleError('getContracts', []))
      );
  }

  getShipments(): Observable<Shipment[]> {
    return this.http.get<Shipment[]>(this.shipmentsUrl)
      .pipe(
        retry(3),
        catchError(this.handleError('getShipments', []))
      );
  }

  getShipmentById(id: string): Observable<Shipment | {}> {
    return this.http.get<Shipment>(`${this.shipmentsUrl}/${id}`)
      .pipe(
        retry(3),
        catchError(this.handleError('getShipmentById'))
      );
  }
```

Comment: https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-multiple-http-requests-with-rxjs

Comment: Does endpoint `/contracts` return an id or value that needs to be used in `/shipments`? Or do you mean the `/contracts` and `/shipments` are called simultaneously, then a subsequent call happens to `/shipments/:id` after the previous ones completed? You may want to make a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) and using `of` or similar to demonstrate the flow and return data structures.

Answer (score 0):

`forkJoin` did the trick.

Thank you for the answer, I didn't knew about this function.
I'm posting here the code maybe it will help someone else having this problem:

```
  getContracts(): void {
    forkJoin(
      this.contractService.getContracts(),
      this.shipmentService.getShipments()
    )
      .subscribe(([contracts, shipments]) => {
        if (Array.isArray(contracts) && Array.isArray(shipments)) {
          this.contracts = contracts
            .map(contract => {
              contract.shipment = shipments.find(shipment => shipment.shipmentId === contract.shipmentId);
              return contract;
            });
        }

        console.log(contracts);
      });
  }
```